# iPhone - Capture device button push

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know you cannot control device volume from within your application, but I would like the device volume to be able to affect the UIScrollBar I have in my application to control volume.

I know this is possible because the Last.fm application does it, I would like to implement this behaviour.

I can find very little information on the interwebs. Anyone here can help me maybe? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's easy with a listener callback

```
void audioVolumeChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inID, UInt32 inDataSize, const void *inData)
{
    RootViewController *controller = (RootViewController *) inUserData;
    Float32 newGain = *(Float32 *)inData;
    [controller setGainManual:newGain]; 
}
```

which gets initialized in my view controller's viewDidLoad like this

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume ,audioVolumeChangeListenerCallback, self );
```

This is all SDK/App Store friendly too.

Comment: Doing it in viewDidLoad is risky as your view can unload if you get a memory warning, and you will sign up for the callback twice.

Comment: i want this to work in background as well. Is there method by which i can achieve this.