# Position of an imageView based on the volume of the volume button of the device

Tags: iphone

I want to position an imageView based on the amount of volume of the device, is it possible to obtain how much sound volume the device (iphone) is actually set to?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a property listener callback function that listens for changes to the `kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume` property.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639721/iphone-capture-device-button-push) gives an example of writing and using the property listener callback function.