# Assigning app functionality to silent/mute switch in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to programmatically link the physical mute/silent switch to an app function?

I would like to use the mute/silent switch as a toggle to lock/unlock aspects of an app (not sound-specific, but the app does not rely on audio so mute or not is actually moot. ;)

Comment: Unless you're in some environment where users aren't allowed to run other apps, this is a bad idea.  The mute switch affects things like incoming call ringing and notifications, which have nothing to do with your app.  Why should the user be forced to affect those things in order to change the way your app behaves?

Comment: I get that, but I am trying to devise a simple way to toggle within part of a toddler aged children's game app. Basically "parental controls" that are accessible only when mute is switched on.

Comment: Apart from anything else, if you use the mute switch for something like this you're definitely asking for trouble from Apple if you try to sell your app on iTunes - it really wouldn't surprise me if they reject it during review for "misusing" the mute switch. Please, if at all possible, don't try things like this.

Comment: Try a long swipe (e.g. all the way along one edge, possibly with multiple touches ) to lock/unlock. I'm working on a toddler app at the moment and that seems quite toddler proof.

Comment: A long swipe or preset swipe pattern may be the solution. Thanks, @jrturton, and best of luck on your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that by capturing the hardware button call back; capturing the callback is explained by @John Fricker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639721/iphone-capture-device-button-push).

But the app may be rejected by apple 'cos as per [app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

```
10.5 Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is only for Lock Rotation or Mute. You can choose it in Settings app.
but it seems to be possible to detect the state of the mute switch.

[How to programmatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch)

Comment: Thanks. I've read that post, but it seems to be specific to audio programming. I was hoping there was a way to program the physical switch to work almost as a pause button/parental control access in a kids' game app. I need to come up with a simple way to disable/enable the touch screen.

Comment: the69geeks's answer is correct. the app will be rejected by App Review Team. how about using shake gesture?

Comment: shake is a possibility, but as i said, it's for toddlers who are prone to shaking things regardless. maybe a long swipe or a preset pattern will work. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, an app That does this will not be rejected by Apple because first, there's already two apps on the AppStore does this. Second the appstore review guidlines say that you cannot alter the standard function, but we are not trying to alter the finction, we are using the same function.